# How do i send an email to user only when he is activated in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i trying to develop a user management system.In here i send an email to user when his account has been created. Now i also want to send an email to him when his status has been activated. For this i used this :

```
        $data = $this->reseller_m->array_from_post(array('sip_username','sip_password','key','allocation_block','name','email','password','phone','balance','user_num','address','country','country_code','created','modified','status'));


                $data['password'] = $this->reseller_m->hash($data['password']);


                $key=$this->reseller_m->save($data, $id);



            if($id === NULL)
                {

                        $config = Array(
                            'protocol' => 'smtp',
                            'smtp_host' => 'mail.temp.com',
                            'smtp_port' => 25,
                            'smtp_user' => 'temp@temp.com',
                            'smtp_pass' => 'temp@1234',
                            );

                        $this->load->library('email', $config);
                        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

                        $this->email->from('temp@bizrtc.com', 'Rajan');
                        $this->email->to($_POST['email']);
                        $this->email->subject('Your Account Has Been SuccessFully Created.');
                        $this->email->message('Hi, We have created your Account. Please Login  : crm/reseller/secure/login');
                        $this->email->send();


                        if ($this->email->send()) 
                        {

                            echo"Success";

                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                           echo '<p class="error_msg">That Email And Password Combination Does Not Exist!</p>';
                        }

                }

                $result = $this->reseller_m->check_mail_status($id);

                        if($result[0]['email_send']==0)
                        {
                                    $config = Array(
                                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                                    'smtp_host' => 'mail.temp.com',
                                    'smtp_port' => 25,
                                    'smtp_user' => 'temp@temp.com',
                                    'smtp_pass' => 'temp@1234',
                                    );


                                $this->load->library('email', $config);
                                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


                                $this->email->from('temp@bizrtc.com', 'Rajan');
                                $this->email->to($_POST['email']);
                                $this->email->subject('Your Account Has Been SuccessFully Activated.');
                                $this->email->message('Hi, We have created your Account. Please Login ');


                                $this->email->send();



                                if ($this->email->send()) 
                                {
                                    echo"Success";

                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                   echo '<p class="error_msg">That Email And Password Combination Does Not Exist !</p>';
                                }

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error 123";
                        die();
                    }
```

This works perfectly but this function is in my edit method so whenever i edit a user it again takes status as post= active and sends mail everytime i edit him. I want to only send an email when his status is changed from active to inactive or vice versa. My edit method checks if i have an id. If I have then edit a user or else create a new.

Comment: show edit method and form also.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll Updating the question code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. Every time when function triggered mail will sent.

Follow these steps

1. Use database field with `email_send` vales with `0` and `1`.
2. `0 ==` no mail sent and `1 ==` for mail sent.
3. Before send check whether valve us `== 0` then only send mail.
4. if `email_send == 0` send mail and update database with `1`

**EDIT 01**

In controller

```
<?
    if($_POST['status'] === 'Active')
    {
        // retrieve user id and assign to $id
        $result = $this->Model_name->check_mail_status($id);

        if($result[0]['email_send']==0)
        {
            $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'mail.temp.com',
                'smtp_port' => 25,
                'smtp_user' => 'temp@temp.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'temp@1234',
            );


            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


            $this->email->from('temp@test.com', 'Rajan');
            $this->email->to($_POST['email']);
            $this->email->subject('Your Account Has Been SuccessFully Activated.');
            $this->email->message('Hi, We have created your Account. Please Login ');



            $this->email->send();

            if ($this->email->send())
            {
                echo"Success";

            }
            else
            {
                echo '<p class="error_msg">That Email And Password Combination Does Not Exist !</p>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p class="error_msg">Mail sent already</p>';
        }        

    }
?>
```

In Model

```
function check_mail_status($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('id', $id );
    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**Edit 02**

alter this in controller code

```
if ($this->email->send())
{
    $this->Model_name->update_email_send($id);

}
```

In model

```
function update_email_send($id)
{
    $data = array(
               'email_send' => 1
            );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('mytable', $data); 
}
```

Comment: Should i use enum as datatype ?

Comment: is this correct  : $this->email->send();


         $this->db->set('1', $email_sent);
         $this->db->insert('reseller');

Comment: is there any session id assign with user??

Comment: yes I do have a session id. But admin logs in so we have a admin session id

Comment: im asking there is user you check `if($_POST['status'] === 'Active')` this user have any ID??

Comment: this become my url when i edit a user :crm/admin/reseller/edit/5 , now 5 is the id of user

Comment: at first i send an email when user is created  and second i send the email when his status is activated

Comment: you gave two method  function update_email_send($id)  and function check_mail_status($id) for model right???

Comment: yep. add both in model

Comment: Did not work see in the code else portion gets executed i mean i get the else
                    {
                        echo "Error 123";
                        die();
                    }

Comment: Yes i did this as you said $result = $this->reseller_m->check_mail_status($id);

Comment: in Model i fetch function check_mail_status($id)
  {
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->where('id', $id );
   $query = $this->db->get('reseller');
   $result = $query->result_array();
   return $result;
  }

Comment: no im asking did you assing `$id = xxx`?? like this any value??

Comment: Also in my database where i have filed called email_sent i have all rows set to 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89224/discussion-between-rajan-and-abdulla).